# Facebook Graph API doesn't return the e-mail data

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the e-mail data from the Facebook Graph API v3.1.

Although I granted all the permissions that could possibly be granted, API still wouldn't return the e-mail data and warns me that email permission is not granted(as you can see on the second screenshot).

My primary e-mail was already verified but I've removed and re-verified it in order to refresh it.

[image: Access Token permissions]

[image: Graph API result]

Any ideas why would it not behave itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just found out that I need to use

`/v3.1/me?fields=email`

instead of

`/{user-id}?fields=email`